# GKGraph GKGraphNode GKGridGraphNode, what's relationship for them?

Tags: sprite-kit, gameplay-kit

I've read the document but still confused of them, could any guy can give me a clearly explaining, e.g.any image comparison? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Wikipedia article on [Pathfinding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pathfinding) might help, as might the related topics on graphs and graph search algorithms linked from there. Beyond that, here's an attempt at a quick explainer.

Nodes are places that someone can be, and their connections to other nodes define someone can travel between places. Together, a collection of (connected) nodes form a graph.

`GKGraphNode` is the most general form of node — these nodes don't know anything about where they are in space, just about their connections to other nodes. (That's enough for basic pathfinding, though... if you have a graph where A is connected to B and B is connected to C, the path from A to C goes through B regardless of where those nodes are located, like below.)

[image][image]

`GKGraph` is a collection of nodes, and provides functions that work the graph as a whole, like [the important one for finding paths](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GKGraph_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/GKGraph/findPathFromNode:toNode:).

`GKGridGraphNode` and `GKGraphNode2D` are specialized versions of `GKGraphNode` that add knowledge of the node's position in space — either integer grid space (like a chessboard) or open 2D space. Once you've added that kind of information, a `GKGraph` containing these kinds of nodes can take distance into account when pathfinding.

For example, look at this image:

[image]

If we're just using `GKGraphNode`, all we're talking about is which nodes are connected to which. So if we ask for the shortest path from A to D, we can get either *ACD* or *ABD*, because it's an qual number of connections either way. But if we use `GKGridGraphNode` or `GKGraphNode2D`, we're looking at the lengths of the lines between nodes, in which case *ACD* is the shortest path.

Once you start locating your nodes in (some sort of coordinate) space, it helps to be able to operate on the graph as a whole in that space. That's where `GKGridGraph` and `GKObstacleGraph` come in.

- `GKGridGraph` works with `GKGridGraphNode`s and lets you do things like create a graph to fill a set of dimensions (say, a 10x10 grid, with diagonal movement allowed) instead of making you create and connect a bunch of nodes yourself.
- `GKObstacleGraph` adds more to free-2D-space graphs by letting you mark areas as impassable obstacles and automatically managing the nodes and connections to route around obstacles.

Hopefully this helps a bit. For more, besides the [reference docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameplayKit/Reference/GameplayKit_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015199) and [guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/GameplayKit_Guide/Pathfinding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015172-CH3-SW1), Apple also has a [WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015-608/) that shows how this stuff works.